# is it correct to select a variable which is not available in data frame? if yes, how?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I just came across a question, in which selection of a data frame variable was done, which was not a part of it. I just selected it as incorrect option. But it was correct. Please help me understand, how it works?

I cross verified code by running in R Console and it ran fine.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
df %>% mutate(xy = paste(x,df$isItPossible))
```

According to me, the statement should throw some error. but it's running correctly."isItPossible" is a variable not available in df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
df$isItPossible
```

it doesn't return an error, it returns `NULL`. This type of stuff is allowed so that you can create new columns with

```
df$isItPossible <- "Yes"
```

And the `paste` function doesn't have a problem with NULL values. It just ignores them.

```
paste("x", NULL)
# [1] "x "
```

But when using `mutate`, you really shouldn't use the `df$` part. It's meant to be run as

```
df %>% mutate(xy = paste(x, isItPossible))
```

which would give you an error about the value not being found which is what you want.